# Basis vectors and Basis Covectors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

If I define a vector so that:

$$ \vec v = v^i e_i = v_i e^i $$

Where $ e_i e^j = \delta _i^j$, then its fair to say that $e_i$ and $e^i$ are dual vectors to eachother. Now from this, we can show that the metric tensor $g_{ij} $ can convert between the **components** of the original basis and the new basis. So we can see this by first directly computing the vector product:

$$ \vec v \cdot \vec v = v^iv^j e_i \cdot e_j = v^i \color{red}{v^j g_{ij}}$$

Then doing it again using the dual representation:

$$ \vec v \cdot \vec v = v^iv_j e_i \cdot e^j = v^i v_j \delta_i^j = v^i\color{red}{v_i} $$

So by equating the red terms here, we can see immediately that:

$$ v_i = v^j g_{ij} $$

Now if the metric tensor transforms the dual component in this way, what I'm trying to figure out is, **how can I express my basis vector in terms of the dual basis vector**.

My initial inclination is to expect that the opposite thing should happen, my reasoning there is:

$$ \vec v = v_ie^i = v^j \color{blue}{g_{ij}e^i} = v^j\color{blue}{e_j}  $$

So then immediately, we can say that:

> $$ e_j = g_{ij}e^i $$

Now this is slightly problematic for me though, because it would imply that differential forms are related to basis vectors such that $ {\partial \over \partial c^i} = g_{ij} dc^i $ which I haven't seen anywhere. so I suppose I'm asking if **there are any errors in my calculations**. The only one I can imagine is that differential forms are covectors, but if the metric tensor converts vectors into covectors, then why can't it do the same to the basis vectors as well?

Comment: But you can't write an equation $\vec v = v^ie_i = v_ie^i$. The two items $v^ie_i$ and $v_ie^i$ are totally different objects: The first is a vector, the second is a covector.

Comment: Well, yes; I agree about that, but theres also a caveat. Theres nothing really wrong with defining $v_i e^i$ as a vector. I haven't made any reference to the fact that $e^i$ is a covector anywhere in my proof. So suppose $e^i$ was a vector for arguments sake, defined so that $e_i e^j = \delta_i^j $

Comment: ps: Your courses rock! Thanks for uploading them :D

Comment: It seems that a few people do this as well, like  this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors#/media/File:Basis.svg

Comment: I am not objecting to the names. I'm saying you cannot write the second equality sign.

Comment: So to be clear, $e_i$ in my definition is a vector, and $e^i$ is also a vector; I know that *usually* it is treated as a co-vector - but I also know a few physicists who never bother using co-vectors at all. But I don't see any issues arising here with me treating it as a vector; in fact - I recover all of the same rules don't I? If it is a vector, I'm just saying that $v_i$ and $v^i$ are its components in two different bases.

Comment: I won't communicate with you anymore if you insist on saying an element of $V$ is an element of $V^*$ and vice versa. No, it's not different bases — it's different vector spaces with (necessarily) different bases. With a metric you can introduce isomorphisms, but not equalities, of those vector spaces. ... As a simple analogy, you have the $xy$-plane and the $zw$-plane in $\Bbb R^4$. Yes, they are both $2$-dimensional and therefore isomorphic. But only the $0$ vector actually lives in them both. You cannot write a fixed vector as lying in each of those $2$-dimensional planes.

Comment: I see, so the isomorphism you'd be using here is the musical isomorphism right? I mean to cause you no offence, I'm trying to understand this material. So is it correct to say $v^ie_i = \flat\left(v_i e^i\right) $? But then continuing from there, you see no further issues?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in what you wrote is that it is not formally correct. Following Jeffrey M. Lee - "Manifolds and differential geometry":

Take $(V,g)$ to be a scalar product space, now since $g$ is nondegenerate, there exists a linear ismorphism $g_\flat:V\to V^*$ defined by:
$$w\mapsto[v\mapsto g_\flat(v)(w)]$$ with
$$g_\flat(v)(w)=g(v,w)$$
in other words:
$$g_\flat(v)=g(v,\cdot)\in V^*$$
We can even define its inverse by $g^\sharp:V^*\to V$, by forcing it to be an isometry bt defining a scalar product on $V^*$:
$$g^*(\alpha,\beta)=g(g^\sharp(\alpha),g^\sharp(\beta))$$
Under this, the dual basis $(e^1,...,e^n)$ corresponding to an orthonormal basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ will also be orthonormal.

As a matter of definition, we will indicate :
$$g_\flat(v)=:v^\flat:=\flat v$$ 
The maps $g_\flat$ and $g^\sharp$ are called musical isomorphisms.

Take now an arbitrary basis $(f_1,...,f_n)$ of $V$ and let $(f^1,...,f^n)$ be the dual basis for $V^*$. The components of $G$ are $g_{ij}=g(f_i,f_j))$ so if $v=v^if_i$ and $w=w^if_i$ then:
$$g(v,w)=g(v^if_i,w^jf_j)=v^iw^jg(f_i,f_j)=v^iw^jg_{ij}$$

Now, since there must be a matrix $(A_{ij})$ such that $\flat f_i=A_{ki}f^k$, and
$$g_{ij}=g(f_i,f_j)=(\flat f_i)(f_j)=A_{ki}f_j=A_{ki}\delta^k_j=A_{ij}$$
Then we have
$$\flat f_i=g_{ik}f^k$$
Thus, for $v=v^if_i$ we have
$$\flat v=v^jg_{ji}f^i$$
in such a way that the components of $\flat v$ are:
$$(\flat v)_i=v^jg_{ji}$$
So, the correct relations that you should have in mind is the latter here. I hope this will make some clarification.

---

EDIT::
In a Riemannian Manifold $M$ you have a metric tensor $\forall p\in M$:
$$g_p:T_pM\times T_pM\to\mathbb{R}$$ 
and then $g_p\in T_pM^*\otimes T_pM^*$ so that it has the form in a local chart $(U,x)$: 
$$g_p=g_{ij}|_pdx^i|_p\otimes dx^j|_p$$ 
where $g_{ij}|_p=g_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigg|_p\right)$.
If you now consider:
$$g_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\bigg|_p,\cdot\right)=g_{ij}|_pdx^i|_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\bigg|_p\right)dx^j|_p=g_{ij}|_p\delta^i_kdx^j|_p=g_{kj}|_pdx^k|_p=:\omega_j|_p$$
And nothing garantees that this $\omega_j|_p$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\bigg|_p$

Comment: I see, so you're saying if I apply the flat operator to the basis covector; everything checks out - I agree with that. But if you took my definitions such that $e_i$ was a basis vector and $e^i$ was just a different basis vector. Then I'm just representing $v$ in two different basis. So the way I've defined things, my $v = v_ie^i $ is equivalent to your covector (I'll call it capital V so its not confusing), so that $ #V = v $. Other than that, our steps are basically identical right?

Comment: The problem is that $\flat f_i$ is not $f_i$